# Once the permission blocked, how to track and "Allow Access" windows firewall security alert

Tags: windows, home-networking, windows-firewall, windows-networking

For time to time, I get a Windows Firewall Security Alert like this:

[image: Windows Firewall Security Alert]

Once I click on "Cancel", I like to be able to change my mind. I like to track the block alerts like above and have another chance to say "Allow Access"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an application, sometimes I just uninstall/restart/reinstall the app and the warning returns.  I see this with the Ubiquiti Controller app

Otherwise, consider resetting Windows Defender Firewall warnings to defaults. That may require resetting some apps.

[Reset firewall warnings](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/70749-restore-default-windows-defender-firewall-settings-windows-10-a.html)

Try the Option 3

> Open Windows Security, and click/tap on the Firewall & network
> protection icon
>
> Click/tap on the Restore firewalls to default link. (see screenshot
> below)

(Screen shot shows "restore firewalls to default).